# Always ask for user input while tkinter gui is running in fullscreen mode

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, tkinter, input

My program needs to track the user input at **all times**. For that i think the input() command is the easiest solution. The problem is: At the same time there should be a Tkinter GUI in fullscreen mode running. I've tried a few things, but nothing really worked out. Here is a simplified program, which shows the problems:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread

def GUI():
  root=tk.Tk()
  Text = Label(master=root, text="Test").pack(side="top")
  Button = Button(master=root, text="Button").pack(side="top")
  root.mainloop()

def input_loop():
  x = input()
  print(x)

t1 = Thread(target=GUI)
t2 = Thread(target=input_loop)

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Even though now both loops work, i still can't type into the console unless I manually select the console window. Other solutions like the entry widget in tkinter won't work because there is no place for them in my actual program. Please let me know if you find something which works reliably.

Comment: What OS are you using? Also why do you need to track the console input at all times? When you make a GUI, usually you don't want the console. And what is the problem with having to manually select the console window?

Answer (score 0):

i didn't get your problem clearly but i will try to help .

so you are saying the program running on full screen but you want to run it on some resolution?

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread

def GUI():
    root=tk.Tk()
    # Program title
    root.title("Title")
    # Preventing user from fullscreen/resize the window
    root.resizable(0, 0)
    # Resolution of the windows in pixles
    root.geometry(f"{820}x{460}")

    Text = Label(master=root, text="Test").pack(side="top")
    Btn = Button(master=root, text="Button").pack(side="top")
    root.mainloop()

def input_loop():
  x = input()
  print(x)

t1 = Thread(target=GUI)
t2 = Thread(target=input_loop)

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

also i changed `button` function to `btn` because i faced an error with it , and you can now complete the program and play with the resolution of the buttons and windows so on .